# Protoplasm alien that absorbs several humans

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a story in my teenage years where some protoplasmic alien eats up several humans from a crashed rocket landing on an alien planet.

They happen to survive as the alien just incorporates them as part of its own body but of course they are mush.

Any ideas which story this is? And who by?

Comment: *Four in One* must be one of [the most asked about stories on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+%22Four+in+One%22).

Comment: Wow. You never know till you know.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like a story by Damon Knight where explorers on a planet were engulfed by a blob but sort of survived and could control it - if they agreed on what to do.

That story is "Four in One":

[Seeking SF short story in which two people swallowed by ectoplasmic blob then start to individuate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42765/seeking-sf-short-story-in-which-two-people-swallowed-by-ectoplasmic-blob-then-st)

http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2009/10/damon-knight-four-in-one-novelette-how.html

https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1953-02/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46235

Comment: I've removed the section about having trouble with your account as it isn't relevant in the answer and not the place for it. That said it's possible that you've accidentally created a guest account on the other site and logged yourself out of your main account. You could try, if the button is available, logging out completely, clearing cookies and then trying to log back in again. If you can't log out, clear your cookies and try as anonymous sessions are cookie based I believe.