# A story of four people landed on a planet and fallen into alien molluscum which consumed them but left brains so they possessed and controlled it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I would be very grateful for the name of this story. I read it in some sci-fi book full of short stories.

One man was a biologist, then a woman also scientist, then a military dude and a state security woman.

The four explored a new planet, saw something looking like a pile of autumn tree leaves, fell into it.  They were swallowed by this alien amoeba-like thing, which inherited and used their brains.

They were encaged all four in the body, and started to grow some legs and eyes.

The latter two wanted to go home, because it's a huge advantage in the war.  The scientists didn't want to become encaged and tested the rest of their lives in some military lab.

They had a fight (all in one body,) growing hands, military dude tried to kill the male scientist with a stone but killed himself, and the security woman damaged the female scientist, she just thought "would be nice if you're gone" and the molluscum defecated her brain.

So at the (happy) end the scientist couple grew legs and arms and so, and went off into sunset, happy and free.

It seems to me it had some name in Latin but I might be wrong.

Comment: "Four in One" again?

Comment: *Four in One* by Damon Knight. This has just been asked about in [Protoplasm alien that absorbs several humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267955/protoplasm-alien-that-absorbs-several-humans). Can you check if this is the story you remember? If so we'll mark this as a duplicate.